# Audio switch with multiple 3.5mm input & outputs

Tags: hardware

I've been searching for a device that simple allows me to pick one input and one output from multiple input/outputs. I thought this would be a called a switch but I can only find ones with one input. Is there such a device that can do this?

I will be attaching various devices, i.e. multiple console sound, PC & Laptop inputs and outputting to my speakers or headphones. I'm looking for something small and simple.

All inputs and outputs are 3.5mm.

Comment: For migration to SD please Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get your hands on some [3.5mm male to 2 RCA male cables](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/24-6270), you could get a stereo source selector like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004RVOEFK).

[image]

I have a similar source selector meant for attaching 4 tape decks to a single receiver.  I still use it on occasion to avoid rewiring when switching between many devices in my system.

Answer (score 0):

Mackie's [HMX-56 headphone matrix mixer](http://www.mackie.com/products/hmx56/) could do the job — it takes 4 inputs and provides 6 individually-mixed outputs.